# QMainWindow' object has no attribute 'QWidget'

Tags: python, pyqt, widget

I am very new, trying to create 14 (7 x pairs of yes/no) of QRadio buttons in Python 4 code to loop over and record for each of the 7Qs whether the yes or no QRadio button was checked. My code is below. I kept getting the following error message:

> 'QMainWindow' object has no attribute 'QWidget'.

I am not sure what I did wrong. As far as I know, in most cases, this type of error involves classes. Thank you very much in advance.

```
rdbObjects = []
numQuestions = 7
firstWidget = 0
for q in range(0,numQuestions):
    widg = window.QWidget2(Ui_Assignment3_MainWindow)
    subWidg = QWidget(widg)
    subWidg.setGeometry(500,q*60,141,421) 
    rdb1 = QRadioButton(subWidg
    rdb1.setGeometry(10,10,41,18)
    rdb2 = QRadioButton(subWidg)
    rdb2.setGeometry(60,10,61,18)
    rdb1.setText('Yes')
    rdb2.setText('No')
    if rdb1.isChecked():
       print ('0')
    else:
      print ('1')
 rdbObjects.select([rdb1, rdb2])
```

Comment: Python 4???????

Comment: Sorry, Python 3.4

Comment: Just so you know before the next time you post a question here: StackOverflow isn't meant to be a debugging service. Ideally, your question will be read by other people who have a similar problem. But this will only help them if you ask good questions. Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you post another question and make sure to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you do this right, you will probably be able to answer your own question before you need to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't see the particular instance of this in the code sample you have provided, this traceback indicates that you have created an instance of `QMainWindow` and attempted to access an attribute `QWidget` from it, something like

```
w = QMainWindow()
w.QWidget
```

But `QMainWindow` doesn't have any attribute by this name, hence the error. In the code sample you provided, it looks like you do something similar in the line

```
widg = window.QWidget2(Ui_Assignment3_MainWindow)
```

I don't know what `window` is, but unless it has a method or function with the name `QWidget2`, this will cause a similar error.